# Local variables with Delegates

Tags: c#, delegates, closures, heap-memory

This <strike>is clearly not</strike> appears like it wouldn't be a best practice. Can someone explain why it would not be a best practice or how this works? Any books or articles  providing an explanation would be appreciated.

```
//The constructor
public Page_Index() {

    //create a local value
    string currentValue = "This is the FIRST value";

    //use the local variable in a delegate that fires later
    this.Load += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Response.Write(currentValue);
    };

    //change it again
    currentValue = "This is the MODIFIED value";

}
```

The value that is output is the second value *"Modified"*. What part of the compiler magic is making this work? Is this as simple as keeping track of the value on the heap and retrieving it again later?

[Edit]: Given some of the comments, changing the original sentence some...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that practice. It is just more advanced than beginners would understand.

Comment: seconded; in fact, it can make for very clean / elegant design - but you do need to understand the implications.

Comment: That's really quite interesting. I wouldn't think messing with local variables within the scope the delegate was assigned would be good practice, but you learn something new all the time.

Comment: It depends on the scenario; in most cases it would be a much better idea to make a second variable that is tightly scoped and never changes - but there are a few use-cases for updated captured variables, But indeed: treat them as read-only until there is a good reason and you'll have much less pain.

Comment: That's the difference between a delegate and a closure. What you've made here is a closure. They are extremely powerful, and the fact that we have closures in .NET is a huge plus, not a minus.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

currentValue is no longer a local variable: it is a *captured* variable. This compiles to something like:

```
class Foo {
  public string currentValue; // yes, it is a field

  public void SomeMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Write(currentValue);
  }
}
...
public Page_Index() {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  foo.currentValue = "This is the FIRST value";
  this.Load += foo.SomeMethod;

  foo.currentValue = "This is the MODIFIED value";
}
```

Jon Skeet has a really good write up of this in [C# in Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet/), and a separate (not as detailed) discussion [here](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx).

Note that the variable currentValue is now on the heap, not the stack - this has lots of implications, not least that it can now be used by various callers.

This is different to java: in java the *value* of a variable is captured. In C#, the *variable itself* is captured.

Comment: As well as writing it up in C# in Depth (thanks for the plug!), I've got an article comparing C# and Java closures and explaining why they're nice:

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx

Comment: Ah - as you were writing that comment, I was editing the above to include it. Double the value ;-p

Comment: @Mark: To slightly improve your great answer, could you exchange " variable *value* " by " *value* of the variable " in your last sentence? Since the variable is called "currentValue" it can confuse the reader (like me), first thinking that the italic " *value* " refers to the *name* of the variable (" which variable? The one called *value* ")

Comment: I recommend Eric Lippert's recent blog post, about how variables stored and managed. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> I suppose more the question I am asking is that how is it working with a local variable
>   [MG edit: "Ack - ignore this..." was added afterwards]

That is the point; it really *isn't* a local variable any more - at least, not in terms of how we normally think of them (on the stack etc). It looks like one, but it isn't.

And for info, re "not good practice" - anonymous methods and captured variables are actually an incredibly powerful tool, *especially* when working with events. Feel free to use them, but if you are going down this route, I would recommend picking up Jon's book to make sure you understand what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the value of the variable within the closure/delegate, else it can be modified, like you saw.

Assign currentValue to a variable local (inside) to the delegate.