# C# issue with dynamically linking variable value in delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a GUI setup code in my game, like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    ...
    Button button = new Button();
    ...
    button.handler = delegate { selectedIndex = i; };
    gui.Add(button);
    ...
}
```

I want to make button changing `selectedIndex` to current value of `i`, that was on it's creation. I.e. button0 changes it to 0, button1 to 1 and so on. But it looks like it dinamycally link value in delegate to `i` variable and all buttons changes `selectedIndex` to `count + 1`.
How to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Local variables with Delegates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148669/local-variables-with-delegates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running into the [common problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) of what gets captured in an anonymous function. You're capturing `i` in the delegate, and that value changes over the course of your loop.

You need a *copy* of `i`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    int copy = i;
    ...
    Button button = new Button();
    ...
    button.handler = delegate { selectedIndex = copy; };
    gui.Add(button);
    ...
}
```

Note that `foreach` loops had the same problem in C# 4, but in C# 5 the iteration variable in a `foreach` loop is a "fresh" variable on each iteration.